# How to go to grub menu in lenovo laptop with single boot ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, lenovo

I gave my laptop to someone for installing ubuntu. Turns out he is not good at it and dont know the root password that he gave while installing ubuntu.I have seen other posts where they talk about pressing shift(and in some case esc) to go to grub menu(to go to recovery mode to solve the issue), but its not working for me.

Any help will be great as currently I have only this laptop and in urgent need for this problem to get resolved.

Comment: It is shift if a BIOS install and escape if UEFI install. And you press key right after UEFI/BIOS screen. But if UEFI setting for fast boot is on, you may not have time to press any key. Then you need cold boot not warm reboot. And if laptop also remove battery. Fully shutdown, hold power switch for 10 sec or so to fully drain all power and then start system. Press correct key right after UEFI/BIOS screen. On my system I often have to try several times.

Comment: I'm curious if you tried the comments of @oldfred and if they worked out better than the answer posted below?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Grub Customizer the Software Centre.  In the General tab, set the "Boot default entry after"  field to 5 seconds or something like that.  Then click "Save".  On your next boot, you will be able to access the Grub menu without going mad trying to catch keyboard presses.

Comment: And how does one install Grub Customizer if one can't login as the question says? The question clearly says they need to reset password, for which one needs to get to grub.